# Error Opencart 2.3 Authorize.net

Tags: checkout, authorize.net, opencart2.3

I am using Opencart 2.3 version and installed an extension of Authorize.net AIM. I configured the API details and Facing getting an error of `(Test Mode) The supplied currency code is either invalid, not supported, not allowed for this merchant or doesn't have an exchange rate.`

Here is the screenshot of settings I configured

[image]

Can anyone help me where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not familiar with opencart but can you set a default currency in it? If so, what is it set to? Also, if possible, can you get the actual call being made to Authorize.Net and post it here?

Comment: I found the fix. The issue was with `x_currency_code` parameter of authorize.net module of opencart. I commented `x_currency_code` parameter and it starts workings fine.